Nodejs trycatch how we are supposed to implement error cause?
in a scenario where I have multiple (nested, composed) functions that, with  try catch blocks are rising exceptions, bubbling up the error from bottom up, I'd like to understand if there's a a way already included with NodeJs functionalities to achieve the possibility to clearly carry up with the final error all the errors instances raised, and the associated error payload.
So to be more explicit here's a code example:
if I have a chain of throws from Error classes custom defined that are holding error related data:

class MyError extends Error {
    cause: unknown;
    constructor(message:string, cause?:unknown) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'MyError';
        this.cause = cause;
    }
}
class InvalidParameterError extends MyError {
    data: unknown;
    constructor(message:string, data:unknown, cause?:unknown) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.name = 'InvalidParameterError';
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class InvalidRequestError extends MyError {
    request: unknown;
    constructor(message:string, request:unknown, cause?:unknown) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.name = 'InvalidRequestError';
        this.request = request;
    }
}


try {
    try{
       throw new InvalidParameterError('errorMsg foo bar', {parameterInput: 'abc'})
    }catch(error){
       throw new InvalidRequestError('request sent is invalid', { requestObject: {foo: 'bar'} }, error)
    }
 }catch(error){
   console.log(error) // here std nodejs stack trace is not providing all needed info
 }

The above will out something that is going to be useful (but I have to withHold some custom made lib):
InvalidRequestError: request sent is invalid
    at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/test.ts:33:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    ... 7 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at bootstrap ([...]/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10) {
  cause: InvalidParameterError: errorMsg foo bar
      at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/test.ts:31:14)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
      at Module.m._compile ([...]/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
      at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] ([...]/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
      at phase4 ([...]/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
      at bootstrap ([...]/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10) {
    cause: undefined,
    data: { parameterInput: 'abc' }
  },
  request: { requestObject: { foo: 'bar' } }
}

I see that Nodejs 23 is supporting
new Error('message error', { cause });

which is something similar, but it doesn't seem to work properly to me.
I'd like to know if there are better practice for this
or if there's some npm package that is widely supported and implementing a more advanced Error handling/debugging....
